# SqlXml: Wrong driver for OLEDB?

Tags: xml, oledb, sqlxml

I am trying to execute this stored proc from sqlxml.  I know that the command never reaches sql server, because I have monitored traffic with the profiler.
There are no parameters and my Exec statement reflects this.
There is a value in the registry for OLEDB_SERVICES and I have tested the connection string with other code that works.
I believe that I might have the wrong driver for oledb but not sure how to figure out what my driver is and  how to replace it.

```
command.CommandText = "Exec SXAVWFOpenWorkflowPr FOR XML NESTED";
command.RootTag = "Workflow";
command.ClientSideXml = true;

XmlReader xr = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
```

My error message is:  Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: I have a similar problem... using SQLXML, I haven't been able to connect to SQL 2008. This site shows an example that might help: http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms171785%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I was getting your error until I used this connection string format:

```
Provider=SQLXMLOLEDB.4.0;Data Provider=SQLNCLI;
Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;
```

However, I'm still not able to make my connection work right, so this may not be correct. I'm now getting "Data provider could not be created" errors :(

I have yet to find a good, authoritative, reference detailing what connection string format is needed by SQLXML.